# Railsで中間テーブルのカラム順に並べ替えたい

Tags: ruby-on-rails

#### 前提・実現したいこと

以下のような関連付けをしているモデルがあります。
Plan=>Course=>Lesson
deviseのモデルUser
中間テーブル
- course_plan
- bookmark

course_planモデルにpositonカラムがあります。
bookmarkのindexページでpositionカラム順にbookmarkを並べ替えたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

```
class Plan
  has_many :users

  has_many :course_plans, -> { order(position: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy

  has_many :courses, -> { includes(:course_plans).order('course_plans.position       ASC') }, through: :course_plans


 class CoursePlan
  belongs_to :course
  belongs_to :plan


 class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lessons, -> { order(chapter: :asc) }, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :lessons
  has_many :course_plans
  has_many :plans, through: :course_plans


class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course
  has_many :bookmarks
  has_many :bookmarked_users, through: :bookmarks, source: :user


class Bookmark < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :lesson
```

#### 試したこと

現在は苦肉の策で
コースIDが若い順、同一コースの場合はレッスンIDが若い方を上にしています。

```
def bookmarks
@bookmarks = Bookmark.where(user_id: current_user.id).sort_bookmarks
@bookmarks = Bookmark.joins(lesson:     [:course]).order("course_id").order("chapter").where(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
```

`joins`や`includes`してみましたが、うまくいきませんでした。
どなたか教えていただけると幸いです。

## 下記回答頂いて、やりたいことまでかなり近づきました!

しかし、これをviewでeach文で取り出したところ、同じブックマークしたレッスンが４つも出てきてしまいました。ログインしているユーザーがブックマークしたレッスンをcourse_planのposition順かつ同一コースの場合はレッスンIDが若い方を上に並べたいです。
下記現在のコードです。

```
controller.rb
def bookmark
 @bookmarks = Bookmark.joins(lesson: { course: :course_plans }).order(CoursePlan.arel_table[:position].desc).where(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

(bookmark.html.erb)

```
        <% if @bookmarks.blank? %>
      <div class="not_found">
        <%= "ブックマークしているレッスンはありません" %>
      </div>
    <% else %>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <table id="memo_table" class="table">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th class="">コース名</th>
                <th class="">ブックマークしたレッスン</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <% @bookmarks.each do |bookmark| %>
                <% if bookmark.present? %>
                  <tr valign="top">
                    <td class="s12">
                      <%= link_to course_path(bookmark.lesson.course) do %>
                        <%= bookmark.lesson.course.title %>
                      <% end %>
                    </td>
                    <td class="s12">
                      <%= link_to lesson_path(bookmark.lesson) do %>
                        <%= bookmark.lesson.title %>
                      <% end %>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/35226 マルチポスト

Answer (score 2):

> course_planモデルにpositonカラムがあります。
>   bookmarkのindexページでpositionカラム順にbookmarkを並べ替えたいのですが、どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

Bookmark から CoursePlan までを繋いで、CoursePlan の position で order すれば良いかと思います。

```
irb(main):009:0> Bookmark.joins(lesson: { course: :course_plans }).order(CoursePlan.arel_table[:position].desc).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"bookmarks\".* FROM \"bookmarks\" INNER JOIN \"lessons\" ON \"lessons\".\"id\" = \"bookmarks\".\"lesson_id\" INNER JOIN \"courses\" ON \"courses\".\"id\" = \"lessons\".\"course_id\" INNER JOIN \"course_plans\" ON \"course_plans\".\"course_id\" = \"courses\".\"id\"  ORDER BY \"course_plans\".\"position\" DESC"
```

ただ、提示されているコードを見ると、それ以外のものも多く含まれていらっしゃいますね。
本当にやりたいことは、もしかして違うのでしょうか……？
その場合は、別途質問を追加されることをお勧めします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
おっしゃっている通りでした。
上記コードで、ログインしているユーザーがブックマークしているレッスンをviewでcourse_planのpositionカラム順に並べて表示したいのですが、おなじブックマークしたレッスンが４つ表示されてしまいました。

    ```@bookmarks = Bookmark.joins(lesson: { course: :course_plans }).order(CoursePlan.arel_table[:position].desc).where(user_id: current_user.id)```